# Android - ListView, why does list.getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.icon) return multiple

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I'm having a strange problem with android ListView & GridView

I have a ListView that is inflated with 100 items and this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/main_screen">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:src="@drawable/icon_1"
      android:onClick="changeIcon" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

public void changeIcon(View view) {
    ImageView myIcon= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    myIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_2);
}
```

If I click on the first icon on the list it does replace the icon that I touched (which is what I want), however, it also replaces icons that are out of the view, not all of them but it happens in a sequence..

So in the pictures, 1 was selected by my touch, 13,25,37 ect.. were selected automatically.. 
And when I scroll back up quickly, my icon change on #1 changes randomly. Sometimes it goes to #2, or #3..

Same problem happens on GridView..

Can anyone explain this behavior and what can I do to avoid this..

Link to screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCFff.jpg

Image 1 is Empty List,
Image 2 is Me clicking on the icon #1,
Image 3 is Shows that also 13 was changed by my touching on #1,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ListView re-uses views once it's scrolled.

You should save the state for each list item independently. That should be done in a custom adapter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.. Any tips on how to save the state on items?